# Dwarf Orange Tree growth problems

Tags: trees, leaves, growth, citrus

My dwarf orange tree has stayed the same since it was put into the backyard about 5 years ago . She has grown 5 oranges that were normal. After that she has stayed the same and grows flowers in the spring and that’s it. Last year she grew oranges but they never matured. The leaves are yellow and seem to be eaten by something. Any ideas on what to do?[image]

[image]
[image]